# which one should i use: Present Participle or Past Participle?

Tags: verbs, past-participles, parts-of-speech, present-participles

What is the difference between using a **Present Participle or Past Participle**?

Original sentence below (from financial times):

> The acquisition marks Asahi's biggest mve as it persues growth outside
>   its **shrinking** home market.

I was thinking about rewitring the sentence in this way:

> ... it **shrunken** home market.

is my sentence wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shrinking home market/Shrunken home market

Shrinking and shrunken are both adjectives in the sentence presented. You can use either adjective in the sentence but there's a difference in meaning. A shrinking home market means a home market that is becoming smaller, whereas a shrunken home market means a home market that has become smaller.